# How to make a char matrix in java,what is the syntax for replacing particular character in that matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, character

Input in row 1 keeps on changing but row 2 is constant,and i want to search a character in row 2 and refer to that index in row 1.

Comment: can you post your code plz?

Comment: It’s all in [the tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), explained much better than you should expect us to do here. Study that, then write your attempt. If you get stuck, ask a much more specific question.

Comment: Can you detail a bit more ?

Answer (score 2):

This is all very basic stuff.  You should read a Java Tutorial or text book.

> How to make a char matrix in java?

Answer:

```
    char[][] matrix = new char[M][N];
```

> What is the syntax for replacing particular character in that matrix?

Answer:

```
    matrix[i][j] = value;
```

> Input in row 1 keeps on changing but row 2 is constant,and i want to search a character in row 2 and refer to that index in row 1.

I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: very nice answer! I have tackled with the unclear part, I kindly ask you to take a look at it, it might give you an idea.

Comment: @LajosArpad - I'm not convinced that you really understand what he / she was asking.  The problem is that the question is unclear.

Comment: I have read it several times as well until I realized the need. There is a row where the values remain unchanged (a row of keys) and there is another row where the values change frequently (a row of values). The goal is to find the value (from the value row) at the index a key is located at (at the key row). I admit it is confusing, but after several reads it got clear for me. At least I think so.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Stephen C's good-quality answer, I would like to tackle the

> Input in row 1 keeps on changing but row 2 is constant,and i want to
>   search a character in row 2 and refer to that index in row 1.

issue. Let's suppose your matrix is called `matrix`. This is how you can search a character in a row:

```
public char getCharIndex(char[][] matrix, int row, char character) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix[row].length; i++) {
        if (character == matrix[row][i]) return i;
    }
    return -1; //Not found
}
```

This is how you can use it:

```
int charIndex = getCharIndex(matrix, 2, 'a');
if (charIndex >= 0) {
    //Do something with matrix[1];
}
```

Since indexing starts from 0, you might have meant 1 instead of 2 and 0 instead of 1. In that case:

```
int charIndex = getCharIndex(matrix, 1, 'a');
if (charIndex >= 0) {
    //Do something with matrix[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=in.nextInt();  //test cases
    while(t-->0){
        char ch[][]=new char[3][3]; //size of matrix 3
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            String s=in.next();  //taking first line as input
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                ch[i][j]=s.charAt(j); // then set all the characters in the matrix
            }
        }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                System.out.print(ch[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```